# access to elements of Tuple in Julia

Tags: julia

I have three matrix like this :

```
f_vp= Array{tuple{Float64,Float64}}(n,m)
f_value1=zeros(n,m)
f_value2=zeros(n,m)
```

the first element of each tuple in `f_vp` is for `f_value1` and the second one is for `f_value2`. for this reason I have to have two l

```
for i=1:m 
     for j=1:n 
           f_value1[j,i] = f_vp[j,i][1] 
           f_value2[j,i] = f_vp[j,i][2] 
     end 
end
```

How can I do this faster? 
and If I want to have something like this :

```
maximum(f_value2-f_value1)
```

can I do that by `f_vp` instead of `f_value1` and `f_value2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That implementation is already fast, but note you can write such loops more succinctly

```
for i=1:m, j = 1:n
....
end
```

WRT to `maximum(f_value2 .- f_value1)` you can also do something like `(x->x[2]-x[1]).(f_vp)` but it shouldn't be faster. You can try it out with BenchmarkTools if you like.